# Please, tell me what I am

Tags: riddle

I'm sorry to say this, but I've got to come clean.

I miss all my brothers, and will start to get mean.

Some may call me yellow, but I'm really quite green.

I'm rough on the edges, but seldom I'm seen.

-

My reason for whining is the job I've been given.

I deal with accidents not easily forgiven.

Back and forth I find myself constantly driven.

But just being held is what makes life worth livin'.

-

I find myself to be in quite a jam...

Can someone please just tell me what I am?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are

> a sponge

I'm sorry to say this, but I've got to come clean.

> used for cleaning things or oneself

I miss all my brothers, and will start to get mean.

> Unclear but maybe because sponges are capable of asexual reproduction ("mean" between male and female) or some geni of sponges are solitary and carnivorous. It might also be a reference to SpongeBob's temperament ;)

Some may call me yellow, but I'm really quite green.

> [image: Scrubbing sponge]

I'm rough on the edges, but seldom I'm seen.

> Inside pots, under water, covered in soap.

My reason for whining is the job I've been given.
I deal with accidents not easily forgiven.

> Scrub too hard and damage the pot.

Back and forth I find myself constantly driven.

> the scrubbing motion

But just being held is what makes life worth livin'.

> only useful when held

I find myself to be in quite a jam...

> sponge cake with jam [image]

Comment: On the right track, but I can't accept an answer without a good explanation.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it is good enough :)

Comment: Close enough! For the second line, i was referencing that sponges often come in packs, but get separated. Also getting "mean" was a play on the word "abrasive". Interesting take on the jam clue, but I had intended the sponge to be currently cleaning a jam stain. Good work!

Answer (score 6):

You are

> A stop light, specifically the yellow light.

I'm sorry to say this, but I've got to come clean.

I miss all my brothers, and will start to get mean

> References the brothers, who are both the green light and red light. Will start to get mean references how aggressive drivers will drive quickly through a yellow light.

Some may call me yellow, but I'm really quite green.

> Yellow lights are actually composed of green, red, and blue. Officially the RGB color for yellow is , (255,255,0), which contains equal parts green and red.

I'm rough on the edges, but seldom I'm seen.

> Rough, indicating how rough it is when you have to drive through a yellow light. You're seldom seen because you only last a few seconds, compared to the other two.

Back and forth I find myself constantly driven.

But just being held is what makes life worth livin'

> Cars drive through yellow lights constantly. A long yellow light is what every driver hopes for when trying to cross the intersection.

I find myself to be in quite a jam...

> A traffic jam!

Can someone please just tell me what I am?

> A yellow light.

Comment: Very clever answer, but not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, are you

> Nails, or toe nails?

I'm sorry to say this, but I've got to come clean.

> You have to clean and cut your nails.

I miss all my brothers, and will start to get mean.

> The toe or finger nails get cut?

Some may call me yellow, but I'm really quite green.

> You may have nail fungus or toe jam?

I'm rough on the edges, but seldom I'm seen.

> They can be rough.

My reason for whining is the job I've been given.

> They walk on everything and touch everything?

I deal with accidents not easily forgiven.

> Stubbing your toe.

Back and forth I find myself constantly driven.

> Using a nail file.

But just being held is what makes life worth livin'.

> On your hand?

I find myself to be in quite a jam...

> Toe jam

Comment: Umm, that sure is wild, but not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it could be (partial one)

> Bitter gourd ( vegetable)

As,

I'm sorry to say this, but I've got to come clean.

> When taken in diet, bitter gourd is supposed to work as a cleansing agent for one's stomach

I miss all my brothers, and will start to get mean.

> It's brothers are - bottle gourd, snake gourd, ridge gourd out of which this one is a kind of odd one - based on its bitter taste

Some may call me yellow, but I'm really quite green.

> Bitter gourd can be in these two colours, though mostly it is of green in colour.

I'm rough on the edges, but seldom I'm seen.

> Usually has scales/ not a smooth surface, though the smooth ones are rare.

-

My reason for whining is the job I've been given.

> Not sure on this..

I deal with accidents not easily forgiven.

> Could be for curing some major gastric diseases, which can be due to *accidental* eating.

Back and forth I find myself constantly driven.

> About symmetry ( vertical) of this vegetable, perhaps.

But just being held is what makes life worth livin'.

> Not sure on this part.

I find myself to be in quite a jam...

> Yes, bitter gourd juice/jam are possible and in use!

Comment: Nope, not the right answer.